# SharePoint 2010: custom masterpage for programmatically created subsites

Tags: sharepoint-2010

What’s the best way to add a custom masterpage to a subsite that is being created programmatically in a feature event receiver?  Each of these 50 subsites gets its own “_catalogs/masterpage”, so I have a feeling that Elements.xml for the root-site’s Module/Elements.xml is out.  More feature receiver code?  PowerShell post-deployment processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this going to be 50 copies of the same Master Page?

If not, I can't really picture how the Master Page will be specially made using code, but also a Feature Module element is certainly out.

But if it is 50 copies of the same file, you could deploy the Master Page to the Gallery one time using a Feature Module element. Then in your Feature Receiver, make a copy of that file with a new name in the Master Page Gallery and attach it to your website:

```
web.MasterUrl = "_catalogs/masterpage/custom_v4.master";
web.CustomMasterUrl = "_catalogs/masterpage/custom_v4.master";
web.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to think about creating 
[custom site definition](http://www.toddbaginski.com/blog/archive/2009/11/02/how-to-create-a-custom-site-definition-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You have following choices to set master page for the site:
1) Using Sharepoint Browser UI (from Site Settings page)
2) Using Custom site definitions 
3) Programmatically 
4) Using SharePoint Designer

Looking at your scenario, no 3 is an option. You may want to do it in the Feature Receiver itself.